# EFI: Problem loading in-kernel X.509 certificate(-65)

Tags: software-installation

I got this error message after installing Ubuntu off of a USB flash drive, I have turned off secure boot but it just appeared with a black screen and nothing happened after that I am booting from a 64 bit OS and I do have the right format USB and product of Ubuntu, can anyone help me out?